# How to properly GROUP BY datetime columns in specific intervals?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, group-by

I am making a stored procedure in MSSQL and I want to group my results by the interval day, I am unsure if this is correct though:

(this is a portion)

```
    INSERT @Results
    (
        [Day],
        [Month],
        [Year],
        [Result]
    )
    SELECT
        DATEPART(DD, DATEADD(MI, @GmtOffset, EventDate)),
        DATEPART(MM, DATEADD(MI, @GmtOffset, EventDate)),
        DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(MI, @GmtOffset, EventDate)),
        Result = CASE WHEN @Metric = 'Take Rate' THEN NULL ELSE COUNT(*) END
    FROM BundleEvent
    WHERE BundleEventTypeId = CASE WHEN @Metric = 'Take Rate' THEN @TypeTakeId ELSE @BundleEventTypeId END
        AND EventDate >= @StartTime AND EventDate <= @EndTime
    GROUP BY
        DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(MI, @GmtOffset, EventDate)),
        DATEPART(MM, DATEADD(MI, @GmtOffset, EventDate)),
        DATEPART(DD, DATEADD(MI, @GmtOffset, EventDate))
```

My fear is it is ultimately going to group the data by the date where the year or month do not matter. Does anyone know if I am doing this correctly? `EventDate` is the `DateTime` field that I want to do a `GROUP BY` on by interval of day.

Thanks

EDIT:
This is the correct way, a simple format exchange... sometimes I need more coffee.

```
INSERT @Results
(
    [Date],
    [Result]
)
SELECT
    CAST(DATEADD(MI, @GmtOffset, BundleEvent.EventDate) AS DATE),
    Result = CASE WHEN @Metric = 'Take Rate' THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(*) END
FROM dbo.BundleEvent WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN dbo.BundleUser WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON BundleEvent.BundleId = BundleUser.BundleId
JOIN dbo.Bundle WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON BundleEvent.BundleId = Bundle.BundleId
WHERE BundleEvent.EventDate >= @StartTimeGmt AND BundleEvent.EventDate <= @EndTimeGmt
    AND BundleEvent.BundleEventTypeId = CASE WHEN @Metric = 'Take Rate' THEN @TypeTakeId ELSE @BundleEventTypeId END
    AND BundleUser.UserId = CASE WHEN @UserId IS NULL THEN BundleUser.UserId ELSE @UserId END
    AND Bundle.BundleType = 1
GROUP BY
    CAST(DATEADD(MI, @GmtOffset, BundleEvent.EventDate) AS DATE)
```

Then I do a sub compare with the format exchange:

```
            CAST(
                (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM dbo.BundleEvent WITH (NOLOCK)
                JOIN dbo.BundleUser WITH (NOLOCK)
                    ON BundleEvent.BundleId = BundleUser.BundleId
                JOIN dbo.Bundle WITH (NOLOCK)
                    ON BundleEvent.BundleId = Bundle.BundleId
                WHERE CAST(DATEADD(MI, @GmtOffset, BundleEvent.EventDate) AS DATE) = [Date]
                AND BundleEvent.BundleEventTypeId = @TypeTakeId
                AND BundleUser.UserId = CASE WHEN @UserId IS NULL THEN BundleUser.UserId ELSE @UserId END
                AND Bundle.BundleType = 1)
                AS DECIMAL(5,2)
```

So in essence the query is matching up correctly and using a new format.

Comment: what does your test data produce?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using and aggregates (except Count(*), Are you sure you want a GROUP BY? Using DISTINCT will produce a single insert entry for all matching dates; perhaps something like:

```
DECLARE @DATE_GMT datetime
SET @DATE_GMT=DATEADD(MI, @GmtOffset, EventDate)
INSERT @Results
(
    [Day],
    [Month],
    [Year],
    [Result]
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    DATEPART(DD, @DATE_GMT),
    DATEPART(MM, @DATE_GMT),
    DATEPART(YY, @DATE_GMT),
    Result = CASE WHEN @Metric = 'Take Rate' THEN NULL ELSE COUNT(*) END
FROM BundleEvent
WHERE BundleEventTypeId = CASE WHEN @Metric = 'Take Rate' THEN @TypeTakeId ELSE @BundleEventTypeId END
    AND EventDate Between @StartTime AND @EndTime
```

Comment: Hi what I did is run the GMT time againse the actual date instead of the start or end period like this: